# What happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list on Android

Tags: android

What happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list on Android? And What difference         between Android and iOS

Answer (score 4):

> What happens when you swipe an app out of the recent apps list on Android?

The process is terminated. AFAIK, it uses the same logic as `killBackgroundProcesses()`.

> And What difference between Android and iOS

iOS is a three-letter term beginning with "i". Android is a seven-letter term beginning with "A".